# data not showing up when using Vue Apollo client

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, graphql, apollo

I am trying to loop through my Wordpress data through in my Vue project.

My script looks like this:

```
<script>
import { useQuery } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const POST_QUERY = gql`
  query GetPostsEdges {
    posts {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default {
  setup() {
    const { result, loading } = useQuery(POST_QUERY);

    console.log(result);
    return { result, loading };
  },
};
</script>
```

And my loop:

```
<div v-if="!loading">
    <p v-for="edge in result.posts.edges.node" :key="edge.id">
      {{ edge.title }}
    </p>
  </div>
```

The data is showing up in the console log but the loop doesn't appear. No errors or anything.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you see `result` properly populated in your vue devtools?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div v-if="result && result.posts">
    <p v-for="edge in result.posts.edges.node" :key="edge.id">
      {{ edge.title }}
    </p>
  </div>
```